# Convert string representation of nested array to Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a string representation of array:

```rb
val1 = "[[\":one\", \":two\"], [\":four\", \":one\"]]"
```

What is the best way to convert it into:

```rb
val2 = [[:one,:two], [:four, :one]]
```

The dimension of array could be **25 x 25**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `YAML.load`:

```
require 'yaml'    
YAML.load(val1.delete ':').map{|x| x.map(&:to_sym)}
# => [[:one, :two], [:four, :one]]
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/ukr/4)

And I guess I should be ready for downvotes, but you can use [`eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval):

```
eval(val1).map{|x| x.map(&method(:eval))}
# => [[:one, :two], [:four, :one]]
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/ukr/5)

Comment: What if the string is too long. Will it slow down the performance?

Comment: @Def: I don't think it really will be that noticeably.

Comment: Let me know if you need help fighting off the angry mob.

Comment: I guess the mob is quite content with `eval` :D

Comment: Just a side question for @Def: How did you get this kind of array representation? Maybe you should try using CSV or JSON (or other known format) instead of trying to concoct your own parser?

Comment: Had you written, `instance_eval val1.delete '"'`, no one would complain. Curious, eh?

Answer (score 8):

Use `JSON.parse`:

```
require 'json'
val2 = JSON.parse val1
# => [[":one", ":two"], [":four", ":one"]]
```

or you can convert them to symbols like this:

```
val2.map{|a,b| [a.sub(/^:/,'').to_sym, b.sub(/^:/,'').to_sym]}
# => [[:one, :two], [:four, :one]]
```

Comment: Note that that does not give exactly what the OP wants, although there may be possibility is that the OP is sloppy, and has asked not what they wanted.

Comment: Consider `sym JSON.parse(val1.tr(':','')) #=> [[:one, :two], [:four, :one]]`, where `def sym(arr); arr.each_with_object([]) { |e,a| a << (e.is_a?(Array) ? sym(e) : e.to_sym) }; end`. Suppose `val1` has another layer of nesting: `val1 = "[[\":one\", [\":two\", \":three\"]], [\":four\", \":one\"]]"`. Then `sym JSON.parse(val1.tr(':','')) #=> [[:one, [:two, :three]], [:four, :one]]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
eval val1.tr('"','') #=> [[:one, :two], [:four, :one]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval val1.gsub '"',''   #=> [[:one,:two], [:four, :one]]
```

Answer (score 0):

val1 = "[[\":one\", \":two\"], [\":four\", \":one\"]]"
puts val1.unpack('Z*Z*')

Descrition:
'unpack' decodes the string  (which may contain binary data). According to the format string, it is returning an array of each value extracted. In the above code, Z stands for null terminated string.